# SPSS Syntax - Nested loop of variables within Do Repeat

Tags: loops, syntax, nested, macros, spss

I've got a dataset with 15 supplier types and 17 product categories. I want to flag whether a given supplier was designated as a "primary" supplier for any of the 17 product categories. I'd like to do this with a nested loop. Here's a basic example of looping through the product categories for the first supplier type:

Here, we're checking whether the first supplier (indicated by the .**1**, suffix -- the second supplier will have a ".**2**" suffix) is the primary supplier for *any* of the product categories, which are indicated by the other index (e.g., QA6R**11**, QA6R**12**, etc.). A Do Repeat makes this easy to do for a single supplier type:

```
* First Supplier Type.

    Compute QA6R_Sup_1 = 0.
    Variable Labels QA6R_Sup_1 "Supplier Type 1". 

        Do Repeat Supplier = QA6R11.1 QA6R12.1 QA6R13.1 QA6R14.1 QA6R15.1 QA6R16.1 QA6R17.1
        QA6R18.1 QA6R19.1 QA6R971.1 QA6R21.1 QA6R22.1 QA6R23.1 QA6R24.1 QA6R25.1 QA6R26.1 QA6R27.1 QA6R972.1.

            If Supplier = 1 QA6R_Sup_1 = 1.

        end repeat.
```

Here, I try to nest the Do Repeat loop in a Product Category loop to avoid plugging and chugging for all 17 product categories, but bugged out because the concatenation wasn't processing in the Do Repeat.

```
define !Suppliers_PrimaryUsed (Categories=!cmdend)
    !do !i !in (!Categories)
        compute !concat("QA6R_Sup_",!i) = 0. 

            Do Repeat Supplier = !concat("QA6R11.",!i) !concat("QA6R12.",!i) !concat("QA6R13.",!i) !concat("QA6R14.",!i) !concat("QA6R15.",!i) !concat("QA6R16.",!i) !concat("QA6R17.",!i
            !concat("QA6R18.",!i) !concat("QA6R19.",!i) !concat("QA6R971.",!i) !concat("QA6R21.",!i) !concat("QA6R22.",!i) !concat("QA6R23.",!i) !concat("QA6R24.",!i)
            !concat("QA6R25.",!i) !concat("QA6R26.",!i) !concat("QA6R27.",!i) !concat("QA6R972.",!i).
                
                 If Supplier = 1 !concat("QA6R_Sup_",!i) = 1.

            end repeat.

          VARIABLE LEVEL !concat("QA6R_Sup_",!i) (NOMINAL).
          ADD VARIABLE LABELS !concat("QA6R_Sup_",!i) 0 "No" 1 "Yes".
    !doend
    exe.
!enddefine.
!Suppliers_PrimaryUsed Categories= 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 97.
```

I want to know whether SPSS syntax can handle this kind of nested loop using an index to pull a list of variables through the code, or whether I need to use Python language to do it.

Or if there's a way simpler way to do it that I'm not seeing (eg. realizing now they're all binary so I can just sum them), that would be awesome and it wouldn't be the first time. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Your macro looks OK as far as I can tell, and should be able to do the job - It appears you have a mistake in the code that caused the failure: missing a right parentheses in `!concat("QA6R17.",!i`

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop could be acheived without actually looping, just use `any` (or `max` or `sum` as you suggested yourself):

```
Compute QA6R_Sup_1 = any(1, QA6R11.1, QA6R12.1, QA6R13.1, QA6R14.1, QA6R15.1,
       QA6R16.1, QA6R17.1, QA6R18.1, QA6R19.1, QA6R971.1, QA6R21.1, QA6R22.1, 
       QA6R23.1, QA6R24.1, QA6R25.1, QA6R26.1, QA6R27.1, QA6R972.1).
```

So the overall loop can be like this (while we're using a macro, might as well go all the way and double loop):

```
define !Suppliers_PrimaryUsed (Cats1=!charend("/")/Cats2=!cmdend)
  !do !i !in (!Cats1)
  compute !concat("QA6R_Sup_",!i) = any(1 !do !j !in (!Cats2) , !concat("QA6R", !j, ".",!i) !doend ). 
  VARIABLE LEVEL !concat("QA6R_Sup_",!i) (NOMINAL).
  ADD VARIABLE LABELS !concat("QA6R_Sup_",!i) 0 "No" 1 "Yes".
  !doend
!enddefine.
!Suppliers_PrimaryUsed Cats1 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 97
            /Cats2 = 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 71 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 72.
```